# Facing error while installing @react-pdf-viewer/pdfjs-dist library

Tags: reactjs, pdf-viewer, pdf-annotations

I am working on online paper correction system I need to use some libraries to upload a PDF and annotate the PDF. So here I use `@react-pdf-viewer/pdfjs-dist` and `PSPDFkit` to add custom annotation in the PDF and end up facing some errors.

When i tried to install `@react-pdf-viewer/pdfjs-dist` library, i'm facing an issue:

[image]

How to resolve this issue? also suggest me any library for PDF annotation other than PSPDFkit in which I can add custom annotation and can download the PDF along with the custom annotation.